# dataframe replace (numeric) categorical values by their frequency of label = 1

Tags: python, dataframe

Here is my dataframe:

```
data = [['a1','b1',0], ['a2','b3',0], ['a1','b2',1], ['a1','b1',1], ['a2','b3',0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns = ['A','B','label'])
```

Except for 'label' column, each col is categorical value (string). I want to replace (numeric) values by their frequency of label = 1, e.g.：

```
n(a1) =  count(A == 'a1' & label = 1)/count(A == 'a1')
```

I used a very stupid way by iterating columns to create a dictionary, then replace df through dictionary. Is there any more simply way?

```
dic = {}
for col, value in df.iteritems():
    if col != 'label':
        for cat in value.unique():
            count = df[value == cat].shape[0]
            positive = df[(value == cat) & (df['label'] == 1)].shape[0]
            dic[cat] = (positive) / count
df.replace(dic, inplace=True)
```

My question is to make the code concise since I naively iterate cols and values. I believe pandas has a lot of convenient functions to achieve this.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand your question.  Can you please provide a sample of the output expected, given your input.  You say you want to replace the numeric fields with the frequency of label, So are you saying you want to replace the label with count_of_label value/Number_of_rows?

Comment: @itprorh66 replace all the value in columns (except label column, use value a1 in A as a example) by: n(a1) =  count(A == 'a1' & label = 1)/count(A == 'a1'). My code is already the result I want. My question is to make the code concise since I naively iterate cols and values. I believe pandas has a lot of convenient functions to achieve this.

Comment: This site isn't designed to improve code.  Suggest you try to ask your question in  [Code Review Forum](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Code Review is a question and answer site for peer programmer code reviews. Please read the relevant guidance related to how to properly ask questions on this site before posting your question.